# Converting a normal SELECT query to a prepared SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, select, prepared-statement

How can I convert this `SELECT` query to a prepared `SELECT` query? I can do `INSERT` prepared statements or `UPDATE` ones, but I get confused with `SELECT` prepared queries as I am never sure what to put for the bind_param's and I do not know how to structure it with the `JOIN`'s

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT up.ordering, u.username, up.playername 
FROM users AS u  
INNER JOIN playersByUser AS up ON u.id = up.userid 
WHERE u.id = $userid 
ORDER BY up.ordering"); 
if (!$stmt) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

I know it would be something like this...

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT up.ordering, u.username, up.playername 
FROM users AS u  
INNER JOIN playersByUser AS up ON u.id = up.userid 
WHERE u.id = $userid 
ORDER BY up.ordering");

if (!$stmt->bind_param("",)) {
echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

I'm just not sure how to bind the params for it or if it is even needed?

Comment: cargo-cult programming: why `bind_param()` when you have NO  parameters in your query? `... where u.id = :userid` would be a parameter...

Comment: So the only `bind_param` I would have is `$userid`? Like this. `if (!$stmt->bind_param("id", $userid)) {
echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}` Then take away the `$userid` from my prepare and put a ? right?

Comment: that's not a parameter. that's a variable you're stuffing into the string. and by the time that string actually gets into the DB layer, the variable will be GONE and replaced with whatever value it had. in other words, you'd still be vulnerable to sql injection attacks,b ecause you've not used the tools correctly. `$userid` - variable, `:userid` - paramter

Comment: @MarcB `:userid` is for PDO. If he's using `bind_param`, that's MySQLi, which uses `?` for placeholders.

Comment: @Barmar: either way, op has no params in the query at all.

Comment: @MarcB True. He's asking us to show him the correct way to do it, because he doesn't understand.

Comment: Isn't this part of what I said, what you guys mean though? Then take away the $userid from my prepare and put a ? right?

Comment: @Paul: Yeah, that's one part of it.  You replace all variable data with a placeholder (the `?`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of prepared statements is so that you are sending the query and the user-inputted values separately.  That way, you can't concat *evil* data and build/run a malicious SQL query.

In your query, you need to use `?`s as placeholders.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT up.ordering, u.username, up.playername 
FROM users AS u  
INNER JOIN playersByUser AS up ON u.id = up.userid 
WHERE u.id = ?
ORDER BY up.ordering");
```

Then you can use `bind_param` to send the value to put in the placeholder.

```
// The 'i' tells SQL what type to use in the query
// Here, it's an int
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userid);
$stmt->execute();
```

(Have a look at the docs for `bind_param` for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

After executing the query, you'll want to use `bind_result` and `fetch` to get the fields:

```
$stmt->bind_result($ordering, $username, $playername);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // The variables $ordering, $username, and $playername
    // will be updated each loop iteration (every time `fetch()` is called)
    echo $playername;
}
```

(The docs for `bind_result` explain how it works: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Comment: So, where you put the 'i', I don't put the column name?

Comment: @Paul: No.  That's not what that that parameter is for.  It's to tell MySQLi what types the parameters are.  See the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Paul: In PDO, the `bindParam` function takes the column name (actually PDO can use named placeholders instead of `?`) and then the variable.  PDO and MySQLi use *different* functions.

Comment: Wow... that completely went over my head. I have done that before, I am so used to there being many moree, so it looks like 'issis'. Not sure why I didn't remember that.

Comment: @Paul: There needs to be one character per each bound variable.  So, it can get messy if you have a lot of parameters.

Answer (score 3):

When you use a prepared query, instead of putting a variable in the query string, you put a placeholder `?`. Then you use `bind_param` to connect the placeholder to the variable.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT up.ordering, u.username, up.playername 
FROM users AS u  
INNER JOIN playersByUser AS up ON u.id = up.userid 
WHERE u.id = ?
ORDER BY up.ordering");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $userid);
$stmt->execute();
```